# MongoDB - Error: document must have an _id before saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've been struggling so much with this project. I am following a tutorial that is out of date in some areas, for instance their version of Jquery used a totally different format for some functions and I had to do a lot of changing around. But I think I am down to one last major problem that I can't seem to find a fix for. In my Schema variable I've got the _id, username, and password types

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    username: String,
    password: String
});
```

but when I go to try to add a new user to my app, instead of getting the alert I am supposed to get, it pops up as [object Object] and nothing gets added to the database. Then this error pops up in the mongo cmd

> "Error: document must have an _id before saving".

I've tried commenting out the _id line and I get the right message but still nothing shows up in my database.

Answer (score 85):

Its pretty simple:

1. If you have declared _id field explicitly in schema, you must initialize it explicitly
2. If you have not declared it in schema, MongoDB will declare and initialize it.

What you can't do, is to have it in the schema but not initialize it. It will throw the error you are talking about

Comment: I  was concerend that if Id is not declared then when finding there will be no id in the document.  But  id is returned, so best is to not declare id in the schema.. cleaner and easier that way

Comment: Simple, but not that evident. Thanks you my good ord

Answer (score 22):

### NestJS with mongoose (@nestjs/mongoose) solution

I fixed the error by

1. Removing `@Prop()` above `_id`
2. Add `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` as type to `_id`

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type CompanyDocument = Company & Document;

@Schema()
export class Company {
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ unique: true })
  name: string;
}

export const CompanySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Company);
```

Comment: Wow this really works out. I guess they don't reflect it but type is inferred?

Answer (score 7):

You can write your model without _id so it will be autogenerated

or

you can use .init() to initialize the document in your DB.

Like:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  username: String,
  password: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

and then

```
const User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/addUser',function(req,res,next){

  User.init() // <- document gets generated

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  })

  user.save().then((data)=>{
    console.log('save data: ',data)
   // what you want to do after saving like res.render
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using mongoose with `nest js` and `GraphQL`, I have fixed it by changing the `id` to `_id` and removing the `@prop` above it even the null value of the `id` problem has vanished. [example on github](https://github.com/malek-laatiri/nestJs-GraphQL-MongoDB-example)

```
import { ObjectType, Field, Int, ID } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from 'src/user/entities/user.entity';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export type SchoolDocument = School & Document;
@ObjectType()
@Schema()
export class School {
  @Prop()//remove this
  @Field(() => ID,{ nullable: true })
  _id: string;
  @Prop()
  @Field(() => String,{ nullable: true })
  name: string;
  @Field(()=>[User],{nullable:true})
  users:User[];
}
export const SchoolSchema= SchemaFactory.createForClass(School);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below snippet I wanted to name _id as userId you can do without it as well.

```js
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});
UserSchema.virtual('userId').get(function(){
    return this._id;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

_id is added automatically by MongoDb.

If you want to keep _id on your data structure be sure to initialize correctly:

```
import { Types } from "mongoose";

const obj = new UserSchema({ 
  "_id": new Types.ObjectId(), 
  "username": "Bill", 
  "password" : "...." 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I accidentally had the following at the end of my Schema. Removing that worked:

```
{ _id: false }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look the way i fixed was i put just id in json post request and not _id.

Answer (score 0):

To make both create and update work without an error. Your schema should have

> _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    username: String,
    password: String
});
```

and the object of this schema should have

> _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()

This creates an id before saving.

```
const user = new UserSchema({ 
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(), 
    username: '...', 
    password : '...' 
});
```

Now this can be saved without an error.

```
return user.save();
```

Answer (score -2):

No need to specify the document _id in your model. The system generates the id automatically if you leave out the _id like so:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({    
    username: String,
    password: String
});
```

That being said, if you still want to generate the _id yourself, see the answers above.