# new document in mongodb keeps getting created how do I prevent this from happening?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, session

I am trying to add a product to a shopping cart in mongodb but the code I have written does not work. It was previously working but when I switched from local mongodb to mongodb atlas cloud and then back to local mongodb it started having issues because it will not use the cart that gets created. instead will keep creating a new cart with a new req.session.cartId belonging to it each time a product is added to the cart. I have had so many issues with this one section and it is the final part of my project to get working before live hosting. Any help is appreciated. thank you.

```
const express = require('express');
const Carts = require('../repo/carts');
const Product = require('../repo/products');
const cartShowTemplate = require('../views/carts/show');

const router = express.Router();
let cart;

router.post('/cart/products', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    cart = await Carts.findById(req.session.cartId);
    // Check if cart exists
    if (!cart) {
      // Create new cart
      cart = await Carts.create({
        // _id: req.session.cartId,
        items: [],
      });
    }

    // Check if product is present
    const productIndex = cart.items.findIndex(
      (item) => item._id === req.body.productId
    );
    if (productIndex === -1) {
      // Create new product
      cart.items.push({
        _id: req.body.productId,
        quantity: 1,
      });
    } else {
      // Update existing product
      cart.items[productIndex].quantity += 1;
    }

    // Save updated cart
    await cart.save();
    console.log(cart);
    res.status(200).send('product added to cart!!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send('there was an error');
  }
});
```

carts repo

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // _id: String,
  items: [
    { quantity: Number, _id: String }
  ]
});

const Carts = new mongoose.model('Carts', cartSchema);

module.exports = Carts;
```

example of whats happening

[image]

as you can see a new object id is assigned to a new cart each time product is added instead of it being the same cart.

Comment: Why is this line commented out? `// _id: req.session.cartId`. If you aren't creating the cart document using the cartId value then how will the system be able to find it later?

Comment: When i uncomment out both of the _id: req,session.cartId it will throw an error saying: MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving

Comment: Have you tried fixing that error? Searching suggests [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952928/mongodb-error-document-must-have-an-id-before-saving) might be relevant

Comment: yes. the only way i've found to not throw the error is to comment out the cartId in the schema then it will add products and create a cart it will also do this if the _id is not declared inside Carts.create as shown in the code above. the error happens even if the id is declared in both carts repo DB file and Carts.create. This code was previously working with both Ids uncommented so I am really confused why its throwing errors now.